# Get component's prop in its event handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

There is a React component with a `key` prop and `onClick` event handler. I need to create some number of these components and give their `key` value as an argument for the click event handler. But if the argument is `value` variable it takes its final value after the iterations of for loop. For example, if I create three components, `handleClick` function gets `value = 3` from every component, but it should be `1` from the first component, `2` from the second and so on.

```
createComponents(n) {
    let value = 0;
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        list.push(
            <Component
            key={value}
            onClick={() => {
                handleClick(value);
            }}
            />
        );
        value += 1;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the key you're setting on `Component`, or the key that the component rendering it receives? Also, are you using class components (as suggested by `this.props.key`) or functional components (as suggested by the freestanding `handleClick`)?

Comment: In general, your best bet is to provide a **runnable** [mcve] in a Stack Snippet. You can add one via the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need the key value that has been set on `Component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` within that arrow function will refer to the component rendering this, not the `Component` instance you're rendering.

Instead of `value`, you can use `i`. Since it's declared within the `for` statement with `let`, a **different* `i` is created for each loop iteration (yes, really). So:

```
createComponents(n) {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        list.push(
            <Component
                key={i}
                onClick={() => {
                  handleClick(i);
                }}
            />
        );
    }
    return list;
}
```

If for some reason `value` and `i` *aren't* the same as they are in your question, you can use a local constant (or variable) within the `for` block to capture `value`'s value:

```
createComponents(n) {
    let value = 0;
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const thisValue = value;
        list.push(
            <Component
                key={thisValue}
                onClick={() => {
                  handleClick(thisValue);
                }}
            />
        );
        ++value;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Since that's declared with `const`, it's local to the block scope created for **each iteration** (just like `i`). That would be true if you used `let` as well (but not `var`).

Comment: Sorry, I did not describe my real problem. I could not use `value` as an argument because it changed every time. I tried to show it in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping issue. handleClick() references value which at time of execution is n - 1 (upper limit of for loop). what you need is to make handleClick() reference a block level variable, like i or introduce another closure in handleClick().

```
 createComponents(n) {
    let value = 0; // do  not use this, all handleclicks will reference last set value
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          list.push(
            <Component
              key={i}
              onClick={() => {
                handleClick(i);
              }}
            />
          );
        }
    return list;

}
```

With above code, you will achieve same thing as `value` changes same as `i`.

You can read more about [closures and lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)